# how to report error for undefined grammar defined using anltr

Tags: parsing, syntax-error, antlr4

I am currently trying to improvise/fix bug an existing grammar which someone else has created.

We have our own language for which we have created an editor We are using eclipse ide.

Some grammar examples like

```
calc : choice INTEGER INTEGER

choice : add|sub|div|mul

INTEGER :   ('0'..'9')+
```

So in my editor, if I type

```
calc add 2 aaa
```

So the error parser of antlr recognizes it as an error since it is expecting an integer and we typed string and throws error message such as

> `extraneous input 'aaa' expecting {'{', INTEGER}"`

(I have my class extends BaseErrorListener, where I create markers for these errors )

Similarly, I have such grammar defined for my editor.

Now the question is: for all this, it identifies that something is wrong in the syntax and it throws errors, but what for syntax which is not part of grammar like

If I type any garbage value such as

```
abc add 2 3
```

or

```
just_type_junk_in_editor
```

it does not throw any error since `‘abc’` or `‘just_type_junk_in_editor‘`  is not in my grammar

so is there a way that for keywords which are not part of grammar, the error parser of antlr should parse it as an error.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When I try to change your grammar into something that actually compiles, I get errors for all of your inputs. Also note that `aaa` isn't part of your grammar any more than `abc` or `just_type_junk_in_editor` are, so that's not the difference between those inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Without having seen the full grammar I think your problem is the missing EOF token in your main rule. ANTLR4 consumes input as much as it can, but if it doesn't match anything at least in the main rule, it ignores the rest, which explains why you don't see an error. By adding EOF you tell your ANTLR4 that all input must be matched:

```
calc: choice INTEGER INTEGER EOF;
```